# Regarding the Caret package in R when apply K fold cross validation

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I have fitted a logistic regression model(using Smarket data set in ISLR package) using caret package in R. Then I calculated the total miss-classification error using (overall test error) K fold cross validation (K=5) as follows,

```
require(ISLR)
require(caret)
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "cv",number = 5)
mod_fit <- train(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Lag5 + Volume,
                 data=Smarket, method="glm",trControl = fitControlcv)

Generalized Linear Model 

1250 samples
   6 predictor
   2 classes: 'Down', 'Up' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation 
Summary of sample sizes: 1249, 1249, 1249, 1249, 1249, 1249, ... 
Resampling results:

  Accuracy  Kappa      
  0.4976    -0.02588095
```

Form the above output i was able to calculate the total miss classification error because ,

total miss classification=1- Accuracy.

**Is there any way to extract the sensitivity and specificity (class specific errors) also from the caret package using K fold cross validation ?**

I was able to calculate sensitivity and specificity in K fold cross validation by creating using by creating a user defined function like mentioned here  : https://youtu.be/AFg2MvhFeho

But i want to know whether  that can be done easily using caret package .

Thank you

Comment: Have you visited <https://rdrr.io/cran/caret/man/sensitivity.html>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by cross tabulating the observed and predicted values as follows,

```
table((mod_fit$pred)$obs,(mod_fit$pred)$pred)
      Down  Up
  Down  125 477
  Up    151 497
```

so

```
overall missclassification = (125+497)/250 = 0.4976

sensitivity =  497/(151+497) = 0.7770
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
confusionMatrix(data = predictions, reference = observations)
```

Should give you what you're looking for and more. You can also see more detail [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/measuring-performance.html#measures-for-predicted-classes).

Comment: As far as i know, this will not work directly if you applied with k fold cross validation.